# Почему у меня идут повторения в цикле при выводе?

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт истории изменений информации о клиенте. Записей в базе по текущему лиду по одной, но выводит почему-то по две! Что может быть?

Структура таблицы `change_history`:

- `id` - `id` в таблице `change_history`
- `id_cabinet` - проект к которому относятся изменения
- `id_lid` - к каком клиенту относятся изменения
- `id_staff` - сотрудник сделавший изменение
- `datetime` - дата изменения
- `vid_change` - вид изменения
- `coment_change` - комментарий изменения
- `change_old` - старая информация
- `change_new` - новая информация

PHP код:

```
[![<?php
$num = 10;
// Извлекаем из URL текущую страницу
@$page = $_GET\['page'\];
// Определяем общее число сообщений в базе данных
$result00 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM change_history WHERE id_lid='".$orders_value\['id'\]."'");
$temp = mysql_fetch_array($result00);
$posts = $temp\[0\];
// Находим общее число страниц
$total = (($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
$total =  intval($total);
// Определяем начало сообщений для текущей страницы
$page = intval($page);
// Если значение $page меньше единицы или отрицательно
// переходим на первую страницу
// А если слишком большое, то переходим на последнюю
if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
  if($page > $total) $page = $total;
// Вычисляем начиная с какого номера
// следует выводить сообщения
$start = $page * $num - $num;
$gt = "yes";
// Выбираем $num сообщений начиная с номера $start  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM change_history WHERE id_lid = '".$orders_value\['id'\]."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $num" ,$db);
if ($result > 0) {

?>

<?
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
do {

  $resultlaed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `lids` WHERE id = '".$myrow\['id_lid'\]."'");
  $lead = mysql_fetch_array($resultlaed);

  $query_staff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['id_staff'\]."' LIMIT 1");
  $staff = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_staff);

  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'name'){
    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
    $title_change = "изменил(а) имя:"; 
    $coment_change = '<span class="name_old">'.$myrow\['change_old'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="name_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'name' and $myrow\['change_old'\] == '') {
    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
    $title_change = "добавил(а) имя:"; 
    $coment_change = ' <span class="name_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'status') {

      $result_status_old = mysql_query("SELECT title, text_color, background_color FROM status WHERE id = '".$myrow\['change_old'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
      $myrow_status_old = mysql_fetch_array($result_status_old);

      $result_status_new = mysql_query("SELECT title, text_color, background_color FROM status WHERE id = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
      $myrow_status_new = mysql_fetch_array($result_status_new);

      if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '') {

        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; $title_change = "изменил(а) статус:";
        $coment_change = '<span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_status_old\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_status_old\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_status_old\['title'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_status_new\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_status_new\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_status_new\['title'\].'</span>';
      }
      if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '') {
        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; $title_change = "добавил(а) статус:";
        $coment_change = '<span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_status_new\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_status_new\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_status_new\['title'\].'</span>';
      }

    }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'note') {
    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>q</div>"; 
    $title_change = "написал(а) заметку:"; 
    $coment_change = $myrow\['coment_change'\];
  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'add') {
    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>d</div>"; 
    $title_change = "добавил(а) клиента:"; 
    $coment_change = $myrow\['coment_change'\];
  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'sendsms') {
    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>'</div>"; 
    $title_change = "отправил(а) sms:"; 
    $coment_change = $myrow\['coment_change'\];
  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'phone') {

    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '') {
      $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
      $title_change = "добавил(а) телефон:"; 
      $coment_change = ' <span class="phone_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
    } 
    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
      $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
      $title_change = "изменил(а) телефон:"; 
      $coment_change = '<span class="phone_old">'.$myrow\['change_old'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="phone_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
    }
  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'deleted') {
    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>g</div>"; 
    $title_change = "удалил(а) клиента:"; 
    $coment_change = '<span class="deleted">Клиент удален</span>';
  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'regain') {
    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon' style='font-size:20px;margin-left:-5px;'>D</div>"; 
    $title_change = "восстановил(а) клиента:"; 
    $coment_change = '<span class="regain">Клиент восстановлен</span>';
  }
  //if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'group' and $myrow\['change_old'\] == '0') {

  //  $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
  //  $title_change = "добавил(а) клиента в группу:"; 

  //    $result_type = mysql_query("SELECT type_title, text_color, background_color FROM group_leads WHERE id_type = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
  //    $myrow_group = mysql_fetch_array($result_type);

  //  $coment_change = ' <span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_group\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_group\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_group\['type_title'\].'</span>';

  //}
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'group') {


      $result_type_old = mysql_query("SELECT type_title, text_color, background_color FROM group_leads WHERE id_type = '".$myrow\['change_old'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
      $myrow_group_old = mysql_fetch_array($result_type_old);

      $result_type_new = mysql_query("SELECT type_title, text_color, background_color FROM group_leads WHERE id_type = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
      $myrow_group_new = mysql_fetch_array($result_type_new);

      if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '0' and $myrow\['change_old'\] !== '') {

        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
        $title_change = "изменил(а) группу клиента:"; 
        $coment_change = ' <span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_group_old\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_group_old\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_group_old\['type_title'\].'</span>  <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div>  <span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_group_new\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_group_new\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_group_new\['type_title'\].'</span> ';

      }
      if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '0' and $myrow\['change_old'\] == '') {

        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
        $title_change = "добавил(а) клиента в группу:"; 

        $coment_change = '<span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_group_new\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_group_new\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_group_new\['type_title'\].'</span> ';

      }


  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'transferlead') {

    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon transferlead'>% v %</div>"; 

    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '0' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '0') {
      $title_change = "изменил(а) ответственного:"; 
      $result_staff_old = mysql_query("SELECT id_staff,name,lastname,email FROM staff WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['change_old'\]."'");
      $myrow_staff_old = mysql_fetch_array($result_staff_old);

      if ($myrow_staff_old\['name'\] !=='' or $myrow_staff_old\['lastname'\] !== '') {
        $name_staff_old = $myrow_staff_old\['name'\]." ".$myrow_staff_old\['lastname'\];
      } else { 
        $name_staff_old = $myrow_staff_old\['email'\];
      }

      $result_staff_new = mysql_query("SELECT id_staff,name,lastname,email FROM staff  WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."'");
      $myrow_staff_new = mysql_fetch_array($result_staff_new);

      if ($myrow_staff_new\['name'\] !=='' or $myrow_staff_new\['lastname'\] !== '') {
        $name_staff_new = $myrow_staff_new\['name'\]." ".$myrow_staff_new\['lastname'\];
      } else { 
        $name_staff_new = $myrow_staff_new\['email'\];
      }

      $coment_change = ' с <span class="name_staff_old">'.$name_staff_old.'</span>  на  <span class="name_staff_new">'.$name_staff_new.'</span> ';

    }
    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '0' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '0') {

      $title_change = "поставил(а) ответственного:"; 
      $result_staff_old = mysql_query("SELECT id_staff,name,lastname FROM staff WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['change_old'\]."'");
      $myrow_staff_old = mysql_fetch_array($result_staff_old);

      $name_staff_old = $myrow_staff_old\['name'\]." ".$myrow_staff_old\['lastname'\];

      $result_staff_new = mysql_query("SELECT id_staff,name,lastname FROM staff WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."'");
      $myrow_staff_new = mysql_fetch_array($result_staff_new);

      $name_staff_new = $myrow_staff_new\['name'\]." ".$myrow_staff_new\['lastname'\];

      $coment_change = '<span class="name_staff_new">'.$name_staff_new.'</span> ';
    }

  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'email') {

    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
      $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
      $title_change = "добавил(а) емайл:"; 
      $coment_change = '<span class="email_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
    }
    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
      $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
      $title_change = "изменил(а) емайл:"; 
      $coment_change = '<span class="email_old">'.$myrow\['change_old'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="email_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
    }

  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'comment') {$vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>7</div>"; $title_change = "добавил(а) комментарий:"; $coment_change = $myrow\['coment_change'\];}

  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'adress') {

      if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>C</div>"; 
        $title_change = "изменил(а) адресс:"; 
        $coment_change = '<span class="adress_old">'.$myrow\['change_old'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="adress_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
      }
      if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>C</div>"; 
        $title_change = "добавил(а) адресс:"; 
        $coment_change = '<span class="adress_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
      }

  }
  if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'tasck') {
    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>J</div>";  
    $title_change = "поставил(а) задачу:"; 
    $result_tasck  = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,description,result,id_connection,time_rem,time_rem_add,status,start_date,start_time,end_date,end_time,id_staff_contractor  FROM tasks WHERE  vid_connection = 'lead' and id_connection = '$myrow\[id_lid\]' and id = '$myrow\[id_data\]'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result_tasck) > 0) {

      $myrow_tasck = mysql_fetch_array($result_tasck);

      $start_datetime = "$myrow_tasck\[start_date\] $myrow_tasck\[start_time\]";
      $end_datetime = "$myrow_tasck\[end_date\] $myrow_tasck\[end_time\]";


      if ($myrow_tasck\['status'\] == '0') {
        $status_tasck = '<div class="o-status-tasck"><div class="text-status">Назначена</div></div>';
      }
      if ($myrow_tasck\['status'\] == '1') {
        $status_tasck = '<div class="ok-status-tasck"><div class="ucrmicon">Q</div> <div class="text-status">Выполнена</div></div>';
        $status_tasck_title = 'Итог';
      }
      if ($myrow_tasck\['status'\] == '2') {
        $status_tasck = '<div class="reject-status-tasck"><div class="ucrmicon">X</div> <div class="text-status">Не выполнена</div></div>';
        $status_tasck_title = 'Почему?';
      }
      if ($myrow_tasck\['result'\] !== '') {

        $itog_tasck = '<div class="tasck-action"><div class="tasck-itog-histori">
                <div class="text-tasck-title">'.$status_tasck_title.'</div>
                  '.$myrow_tasck\['result'\].'
                </div></div>';
        }
      $coment_change ='<div class="tasck-block-histori">
          <div class="tasck-block-title">Задача <div class="tasck-status tasck-status-'.$myrow_tasck\['id'\].'">'.$status_tasck.'</div></div>
          <div class="tasck-content">

            <div class="tasck-title">Название: <span>'.$myrow_tasck\[title\].'</span></div>
            <div class="tasck-date-end">Дата начала: <span>'.new_time(strtotime($start_datetime)).'</span></div>
            <div class="tasck-date-end">Дата окончания: <span>'.new_time(strtotime($end_datetime)).'</span></div>
            <div class="tasck-comment">Комментарий: <span>'.$myrow_tasck\[description\].'</span></div>

            '.$itog_tasck.'

          </div>
        </div>';
    }

  }

?>
  <div class="note-block ">
    <?=$vid_icon;?> <div class="note-bloks-datetime <?=$myrow\['vid_change'\]?>"><? echo new_time(strtotime($myrow\['datetime'\])); ?>, <span><? if ($staff\['name'\] == '' and $staff\['lastname'\] == '') {echo $staff\['email'\];} else { echo "$staff\[name\] $staff\[lastname\]";} ?></span>, <?=$title_change;?></div>

    <div class="note-bloks-vid_change"><?=$coment_change;?></div>

  </div>  

<?
}
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>
</ul>
<?
} else {echo "<div class='alert alert-error' style='margin:40px;width:80%;text-align:center;'><b>Пусто!</b> - изменения касающиеся данного лида еще не вносились.</div>";}
?>
<?php
// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки назад
if ($page != 1) $pervpage = '<a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-1>Первая</a>';
// Проверяем нужны ли стрелки вперед
if ($page != $total) $nextpage = '<a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-' .$total. '>Последняя</a>';

// Находим две ближайшие станицы с обоих краев, если они есть
if($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-'. ($page - 1) .'>'. ($page - 1) .'</a>';
if($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = ' <a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-'. ($page - 2) .'>'. ($page - 2) .'</a>';
if($page - 3 > 0) $page3left = ' <a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-'. ($page - 3) .'>'. ($page - 3) .'</a>';
if($page - 4 > 0) $page4left = ' <a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-'. ($page - 4) .'>'. ($page - 4) .'</a>';




if($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = ' <a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-'. ($page + 1) .'>'. ($page + 1) .'</a>';
if($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = ' <a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-'. ($page + 2) .'>'. ($page + 2) .'</a>';
if($page + 3 <= $total) $page3right = ' <a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-'. ($page + 3) .'>'. ($page + 3) .'</a>';
if($page + 4 <= $total) $page4right = ' <a href=/'.$id_cabinet.'/leads/details-'.$_GET\['edit'\].'/page-'. ($page + 4) .'>'. ($page + 4) .'</a>';





// Вывод меню если страниц больше одной

if ($total > 1)
{
Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
echo "<div class=\"pstrnav\">";
echo $pervpage.$page4left.$page3left.$page2left.$page1left.'<b class="page">'.$page.'</b>'.$page1right.$page2right.$page3right.$page4right.$nextpage;
echo "</div>";
}
?>][1]][1]
```

**P.S.** Извините за говнокод!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить ваш цикл do {} while () на обычный while () {}:

```
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                            $resultlaed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `lids` WHERE id = '".$myrow\['id_lid'\]."'");
                            $lead = mysql_fetch_array($resultlaed);

                            $query_staff = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['id_staff'\]."' LIMIT 1");
                            $staff = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_staff);

                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'name'){
                                $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
                                $title_change = "изменил(а) имя:"; 
                                $coment_change = '<span class="name_old">'.$myrow\['change_old'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="name_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'name' and $myrow\['change_old'\] == '') {
                                $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
                                $title_change = "добавил(а) имя:"; 
                                $coment_change = ' <span class="name_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'status') {

                                    $result_status_old = mysql_query("SELECT title, text_color, background_color FROM status WHERE id = '".$myrow\['change_old'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
                                    $myrow_status_old = mysql_fetch_array($result_status_old);

                                    $result_status_new = mysql_query("SELECT title, text_color, background_color FROM status WHERE id = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
                                    $myrow_status_new = mysql_fetch_array($result_status_new);

                                    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '') {

                                        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; $title_change = "изменил(а) статус:";
                                        $coment_change = '<span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_status_old\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_status_old\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_status_old\['title'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_status_new\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_status_new\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_status_new\['title'\].'</span>';
                                    }
                                    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '') {
                                        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; $title_change = "добавил(а) статус:";
                                        $coment_change = '<span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_status_new\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_status_new\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_status_new\['title'\].'</span>';
                                    }

                                }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'note') {
                                $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>q</div>"; 
                                $title_change = "написал(а) заметку:"; 
                                $coment_change = $myrow\['coment_change'\];
                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'add') {
                                $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>d</div>"; 
                                $title_change = "добавил(а) клиента:"; 
                                $coment_change = $myrow\['coment_change'\];
                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'sendsms') {
                                $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>'</div>"; 
                                $title_change = "отправил(а) sms:"; 
                                $coment_change = $myrow\['coment_change'\];
                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'phone') {

                                if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '') {
                                    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
                                    $title_change = "добавил(а) телефон:"; 
                                    $coment_change = ' <span class="phone_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
                                } 
                                if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
                                    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
                                    $title_change = "изменил(а) телефон:"; 
                                    $coment_change = '<span class="phone_old">'.$myrow\['change_old'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="phone_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
                                }
                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'deleted') {
                                $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>g</div>"; 
                                $title_change = "удалил(а) клиента:"; 
                                $coment_change = '<span class="deleted">Клиент удален</span>';
                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'regain') {
                                $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon' style='font-size:20px;margin-left:-5px;'>D</div>"; 
                                $title_change = "восстановил(а) клиента:"; 
                                $coment_change = '<span class="regain">Клиент восстановлен</span>';
                            }
                            //if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'group' and $myrow\['change_old'\] == '0') {

                            //  $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
                            //  $title_change = "добавил(а) клиента в группу:"; 

                            //      $result_type = mysql_query("SELECT type_title, text_color, background_color FROM group_leads WHERE id_type = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
                            //      $myrow_group = mysql_fetch_array($result_type);

                            //  $coment_change = ' <span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_group\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_group\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_group\['type_title'\].'</span>';

                            //}
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'group') {


                                    $result_type_old = mysql_query("SELECT type_title, text_color, background_color FROM group_leads WHERE id_type = '".$myrow\['change_old'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
                                    $myrow_group_old = mysql_fetch_array($result_type_old);

                                    $result_type_new = mysql_query("SELECT type_title, text_color, background_color FROM group_leads WHERE id_type = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."' and id_cabinet = '".$id_cabinet."' ORDER BY drag");
                                    $myrow_group_new = mysql_fetch_array($result_type_new);

                                    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '0' and $myrow\['change_old'\] !== '') {

                                        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
                                        $title_change = "изменил(а) группу клиента:"; 
                                        $coment_change = ' <span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_group_old\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_group_old\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_group_old\['type_title'\].'</span>  <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div>  <span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_group_new\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_group_new\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_group_new\['type_title'\].'</span> ';

                                    }
                                    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '0' and $myrow\['change_old'\] == '') {

                                        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
                                        $title_change = "добавил(а) клиента в группу:"; 

                                        $coment_change = '<span class="status-lids" style="background-color:'.$myrow_group_new\['background_color'\].';color:'.$myrow_group_new\['text_color'\].'">'.$myrow_group_new\['type_title'\].'</span> ';

                                    }


                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'transferlead') {

                                $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon transferlead'>% v %</div>"; 

                                if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '0' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '0') {
                                    $title_change = "изменил(а) ответственного:"; 
                                    $result_staff_old = mysql_query("SELECT id_staff,name,lastname,email FROM staff WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['change_old'\]."'");
                                    $myrow_staff_old = mysql_fetch_array($result_staff_old);

                                    if ($myrow_staff_old\['name'\] !=='' or $myrow_staff_old\['lastname'\] !== '') {
                                        $name_staff_old = $myrow_staff_old\['name'\]." ".$myrow_staff_old\['lastname'\];
                                    } else { 
                                        $name_staff_old = $myrow_staff_old\['email'\];
                                    }

                                    $result_staff_new = mysql_query("SELECT id_staff,name,lastname,email FROM staff  WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."'");
                                    $myrow_staff_new = mysql_fetch_array($result_staff_new);

                                    if ($myrow_staff_new\['name'\] !=='' or $myrow_staff_new\['lastname'\] !== '') {
                                        $name_staff_new = $myrow_staff_new\['name'\]." ".$myrow_staff_new\['lastname'\];
                                    } else { 
                                        $name_staff_new = $myrow_staff_new\['email'\];
                                    }

                                    $coment_change = ' с <span class="name_staff_old">'.$name_staff_old.'</span>  на  <span class="name_staff_new">'.$name_staff_new.'</span> ';

                                }
                                if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '0' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '0') {

                                    $title_change = "поставил(а) ответственного:"; 
                                    $result_staff_old = mysql_query("SELECT id_staff,name,lastname FROM staff WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['change_old'\]."'");
                                    $myrow_staff_old = mysql_fetch_array($result_staff_old);

                                    $name_staff_old = $myrow_staff_old\['name'\]." ".$myrow_staff_old\['lastname'\];

                                    $result_staff_new = mysql_query("SELECT id_staff,name,lastname FROM staff WHERE id_staff = '".$myrow\['change_new'\]."'");
                                    $myrow_staff_new = mysql_fetch_array($result_staff_new);

                                    $name_staff_new = $myrow_staff_new\['name'\]." ".$myrow_staff_new\['lastname'\];

                                    $coment_change = '<span class="name_staff_new">'.$name_staff_new.'</span> ';
                                }

                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'email') {

                                if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
                                    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
                                    $title_change = "добавил(а) емайл:"; 
                                    $coment_change = '<span class="email_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
                                }
                                if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
                                    $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>f</div>"; 
                                    $title_change = "изменил(а) емайл:"; 
                                    $coment_change = '<span class="email_old">'.$myrow\['change_old'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="email_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
                                }

                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'comment') {$vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>7</div>"; $title_change = "добавил(а) комментарий:"; $coment_change = $myrow\['coment_change'\];}

                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'adress') {

                                    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] !== '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
                                        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>C</div>"; 
                                        $title_change = "изменил(а) адресс:"; 
                                        $coment_change = '<span class="adress_old">'.$myrow\['change_old'\].'</span> <div class="ucrmicon '.$myrow\['vid_change'\].'">9</div> <span class="adress_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
                                    }
                                    if ($myrow\['change_old'\] == '' and $myrow\['change_new'\] !== '') {
                                        $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>C</div>"; 
                                        $title_change = "добавил(а) адресс:"; 
                                        $coment_change = '<span class="adress_new">'.$myrow\['change_new'\].'</span>';
                                    }

                            }
                            if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'tasck') {
                                $vid_icon = "<div class='ucrmicon'>J</div>";  
                                $title_change = "поставил(а) задачу:"; 
                                $result_tasck  = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,description,result,id_connection,time_rem,time_rem_add,status,start_date,start_time,end_date,end_time,id_staff_contractor  FROM tasks WHERE  vid_connection = 'lead' and id_connection = '$myrow\[id_lid\]' and id = '$myrow\[id_data\]'");
                                if (mysql_num_rows($result_tasck) > 0) {

                                    $myrow_tasck = mysql_fetch_array($result_tasck);

                                    $start_datetime = "$myrow_tasck\[start_date\] $myrow_tasck\[start_time\]";
                                    $end_datetime = "$myrow_tasck\[end_date\] $myrow_tasck\[end_time\]";


                                    if ($myrow_tasck\['status'\] == '0') {
                                        $status_tasck = '<div class="o-status-tasck"><div class="text-status">Назначена</div></div>';
                                    }
                                    if ($myrow_tasck\['status'\] == '1') {
                                        $status_tasck = '<div class="ok-status-tasck"><div class="ucrmicon">Q</div> <div class="text-status">Выполнена</div></div>';
                                        $status_tasck_title = 'Итог';
                                    }
                                    if ($myrow_tasck\['status'\] == '2') {
                                        $status_tasck = '<div class="reject-status-tasck"><div class="ucrmicon">X</div> <div class="text-status">Не выполнена</div></div>';
                                        $status_tasck_title = 'Почему?';
                                    }
                                    if ($myrow_tasck\['result'\] !== '') {

                                        $itog_tasck = '<div class="tasck-action"><div class="tasck-itog-histori">
                                                        <div class="text-tasck-title">'.$status_tasck_title.'</div>
                                                            '.$myrow_tasck\['result'\].'
                                                        </div></div>';
                                        }
                                    $coment_change ='<div class="tasck-block-histori">
                                            <div class="tasck-block-title">Задача <div class="tasck-status tasck-status-'.$myrow_tasck\['id'\].'">'.$status_tasck.'</div></div>
                                            <div class="tasck-content">

                                                <div class="tasck-title">Название: <span>'.$myrow_tasck\[title\].'</span></div>
                                                <div class="tasck-date-end">Дата начала: <span>'.new_time(strtotime($start_datetime)).'</span></div>
                                                <div class="tasck-date-end">Дата окончания: <span>'.new_time(strtotime($end_datetime)).'</span></div>
                                                <div class="tasck-comment">Комментарий: <span>'.$myrow_tasck\[description\].'</span></div>

                                                '.$itog_tasck.'

                                            </div>
                                        </div>';
                                }

                            }

                        ?>
                            <div class="note-block ">
                                <?=$vid_icon;?> <div class="note-bloks-datetime <?=$myrow\['vid_change'\]?>"><? echo new_time(strtotime($myrow\['datetime'\])); ?>, <span><? if ($staff\['name'\] == '' and $staff\['lastname'\] == '') {echo $staff\['email'\];} else { echo "$staff\[name\] $staff\[lastname\]";} ?></span>, <?=$title_change;?></div>

                                <div class="note-bloks-vid_change"><?=$coment_change;?></div>

                            </div>  

                        <?
}
```

П.с. у вас код за бекслешен весь... поэтому, возможно, сходу последовательность "скопировал-вставил-заработало" не сработает - нужно все бекслеши убрать (например в `if ($myrow\['vid_change'\] == 'name'){` нужно `if ($myrow['vid_change'] == 'name'){` ). Если же вы это дернули из какой-то вставки и оно у вас прямо так и работало, тогда все будет работать и в таком виде.